# Is there a tool for managing file extensions and their respective program command lines?

Tags: command-line, windows-8, windows-registry, file-association

I'm trying to associate `.appx` files with a utility I wrote which needs a command line similar to `appinstaller --install-only --force path\to\appxfile.appx`. It also must run as an administrator

I tried looking into the registry and editing it, but I can't quite figure it out. What I've done so far is just use the built-in explorer association to associate with the file. This works and also pops up a UAC prompt as it is suppose to, but my program doesn't receive the `--install-only --force` command line bit

Are there any tools for Windows 8 to manage file associations, or an easy manual way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows 7 had two commands, `ftype` and `assoc`. I assume Windows 8 still has them (can't quite check right now).

`ftype` is used to associate a file type name (?) with a command string, e.g. `ftype WinAppPackage=appinstaller --install-only --force %1`

`assoc` is used to associate a file extension with the name, e.g. `assoc .appx=WinAppPackage`

---

Alternatively, you could link the file extension to a batch file using the Windows 8 GUI (`Open With...`). The batch file could contain the following:

```
appinstaller --install-only --force %1
```

Comment: Windows 8 also has them.

Comment: The batch file worked wonderfully and is easy to change later if needed :)

Comment: JFTR, Windows XP had these commands, too.